Closing a Openbook V2 for refund SOLANA. How do I make it work?
So technically is it possibile to close an existing openbook and get the Solana i spent on it.
How do I do this? I found this
https://github.com/openbook-dex/scripts-v2/blob/main/close_market.ts
but I an't implement it. How do I execute this and get the refund?
My openbook is DHpuMPXeGqjCEqYGALdTJFPeA7BGLVKB441f2opHCBQg
I tried implementing this https://github.com/openbook-dex/scripts-v2/blob/main/close_market.ts but i guess i am not good enough at coding
